# Find all possible combinations of paired elements between two arrays, without repeating any of the elements from either array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, logic

I'm trying to figure out the logic for a function that will find all possible combinations of the elements between two source arrays, without repeating any of the elements from either array.

In other words, the elements in each source array are treated as finite resources. From this, a combination of pairs is built until either source array runs out of elements, then the next combination of pairs, then the next, until all permutations have been accounted for.

So for example,

`get_combinations( [1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"] );`

should return

```
    [ [1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"] ],
    [ [1, "a"], [2, "c"], [3, "b"] ],
    [ [1, "b"], [2, "a"], [3, "c"] ],
    [ [1, "b"], [2, "c"], [3, "a"] ],
    [ [1, "c"], [2, "a"], [3, "b"] ],
    [ [1, "c"], [2, "b"], [3, "a"] ]
]
```

(formatted for clarity)

I will be using this for a PHP based project, but I am primarily looking for an algorithm, not a language-specific implementation.

---

As an example with arrays of inequal sizes,

`get_combinations( [1, 2, 3, 4] and ["a", "b"] );`

would return

```
    [ [1, "a"], [2, "b"] ], [ [1, "a"], [3, "b"] ], [ [1, "a"], [4, "b"] ],
    [ [2, "a"], [1, "b"] ], [ [2, "a"], [3, "b"] ], [ [2, "a"], [4, "b"] ],
    [ [3, "a"], [1, "b"] ], [ [3, "a"], [2, "b"] ], [ [3, "a"], [4, "b"] ],
    [ [4, "a"], [1, "b"] ], [ [4, "a"], [2, "b"] ], [ [4, "a"], [3, "b"] ]
]
```

Comment: So result is just all permutations of the second array, combined with initial sequence of the first array. It is easy to find PHP implementation of array permutations (recursive for rather small arrays, next_permutation approach for iterative way). Or your problem is really more hard?

Comment: It works out that way if both arrays are of the same size. Otherwise, it doesn’t hold up.

Comment: @Malkalypse, the same size is not required, can be work with variable length of arrays as well. see the code i have given.

Comment: @Malkalypse  It is worth to show desired result for distinct size arrays.

Comment: I added an example for unequal size arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a programmer who has helped me in the past to solve this one as a php implementation. This is the code she provided, with a few small adjustments and comments added.

```
class GetArrayPermutations{

    public $_arrays;
    public $_order = 0;

    public $_array_combinations;
    public $_array_permutations;

    public function __construct( $arrays ){
        $this->_arrays = $arrays;
        $this->_array_combinations = $this->get_array_combinations( $arrays );
        $this->_array_permutations = $this->get_array_permutations( $this->_array_combinations );
    }


    public function get_array_combinations( $arrays ){
        
        // Order array elements to ensure larger array is second
        if( sizeof( $arrays[0] ) > sizeof( $arrays[1] ) ){
            $arrays = array_reverse($arrays);
            $this->_order = 1;
        }
        
        //$arrays = array_values( $arrays );
        $second = sizeof( $arrays[1] );     
        $size   = sizeof( $arrays[0] ) * $second;
        $result = array(); // initialize $result as an array

        // Collect all possible combinations of arrays
        for( $i = 0; $i < $size; $i++ ){

            // Initialize array for index
            $result[$i] = array(); 

            // Store one value from each array together
            for( $j = 0; $j < 2; $j++ ){        
                array_push( $result[$i], current( $arrays[$j] ) );
            }

            // Advance through combinations
            for ($j = 1; $j >= 0; $j-- ){
                if( next( $arrays[$j] ) ) break;
                if( isset( $arrays[$j] ) ) reset( $arrays[$j] );
            }

        }

        $output = [];
        $output2 = [];

        // Combine values of $result into arrays with shared first value and unique second value
        foreach( $result as $key => $value ){

            // Add key/value pair to $output subarray
            $output += [$key => $value];

            // Once each sub-array is finished
            // Add the sub-array to $output2 and start a fresh sub-array    
            if( ( $key + 1 ) % $second == 0 ){  
                array_push( $output2, $output );
                $output = [];
            }

        }

        return $output2;

    }


    public function get_array_permutations( $arrays ){

        //$arrays = array_values( $arrays );
        $sizeIn = sizeof( $arrays );
        $size   = pow( sizeof( $arrays[0] ), $sizeIn );
        $result = array();  

        // Collect all possible permutations of arrays
        for( $i = 0; $i < $size; $i++ ){

            // Initialize array for index
            $result[$i] = array();

            // Store combination of values from arrays
            for ($j = 0; $j < $sizeIn; $j ++){
                array_push( $result[$i], current( $arrays[$j] ) );
            }

            // Advance through combinations
            for ($j = $sizeIn - 1; $j >= 0; $j--){
                if( next( $arrays[$j] ) ) break;
                if( isset( $arrays[$j] ) ) reset( $arrays[$j] );
            }

        }

        $output = [];
        $output2 = [];
        
        // Iterate through values of $result array
        foreach( $result as $key => $value) {

            // Collect unique second values from each sub-array
            $tempArr = array_unique( array_column( $value, '1' ) );

            if( sizeof( $value ) == sizeof( $tempArr ) ){ // if all second sub-array values are unique

                // Restore input array value sequence, if necessary
                if( $this->_order == 1){
                    foreach( $value as $k => $val ){
                        $temp       = $val[0];
                        $val[0]     = $val[1];
                        $val[1]     = $temp;
                        $value[$k]  = $val;
                    }
                }

                // Add key/value pair to $output
                $output += [$key => $value];

            }

        }

        return $output;

    }

}

$GAP = new GetArrayPermutations( array(
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    ["a", "b", "c", "d"]    
) );

echo '<pre>'; print_r( $GAP->_array_permutations ); echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score -1):

### You can use this algorithm to find the combination. This will work more than two arrays as well.

```
static void print(List<string>[] arr)
{
    int[] indices = new int[arr.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        indices[i] = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        // Print current combination
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            Console.Write(arr[i][indices[i]] + " ");

        Console.WriteLine();
        int next = arr.Length - 1;
        while (next >= 0 &&
              (indices[next] + 1 >=
               arr[next].Count))
            next--;
        if (next < 0)
            return;
        indices[next]++;
        for (int i = next + 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
            indices[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

**call the above method from main**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string>[] arr = new List<string>[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        arr[i] = new List<string>();

    // Now entering data
    // [["1", "2", "3"], ["a", "b", "c"]]
    arr[0].Add("1");
    arr[0].Add("2");
    arr[0].Add("3");
    arr[1].Add("a");
    arr[1].Add("b");
    arr[1].Add("c");

    print(arr);
}
```

// **Input** => [["1", "2", "3"], ["a", "b", "c"]]

// **output**

1 a

1 b

1 c

2 a

2 b

2 c

3 a

3 b

3 c

// **Input** => [["1", "2", "3"], ["a", "b", "c"], ["x", "y", "z"]]

```
List<string>[] arr = new List<string>[3];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    arr[i] = new List<string>();

// Now entering data
// [["1", "2", "3"], ["a", "b", "c"], ["x", "y", "z"]]
arr[0].Add("1");
arr[0].Add("2");
arr[0].Add("3");
arr[1].Add("a");
arr[1].Add("b");
arr[1].Add("c");
arr[2].Add("x");
arr[2].Add("y");
arr[2].Add("z");
```

//**output**

1 a x

1 a y

1 a z

1 b x

1 b y

1 b z

1 c x

1 c y

1 c z

2 a x

2 a y

2 a z

2 b x

2 b y

2 b z

2 c x

2 c y

2 c z

3 a x

3 a y

3 a z

3 b x

3 b y

3 b z

3 c x

3 c y

3 c z

Even this can work with variable length of arrays e.g.

// **Input** => [["1", "2", "3"], ["x"], ["a", "b"]]

//**Output** =>

1 x a

1 x b

2 x a

2 x b

3 x a

3 x b

Comment: I'm afraid this is not what I'm asking for. These are simply individual paired (or tripled etc) values. I need the pairs grouped together into combinations that use all the values of at least one of the source arrays.